# Determine if a string only contains invisible characters in Swift

Tags: swift, string

I was parsing a messy XML. I found many of the nodes contain invisible characters only, for instance:

- `"\n   "`
- `" "`
- `"\t "`
- `"\n           "`
- `"\n\n"`

I saw some posts and answers about alphabet and numbers, but the XML being parsed in my project includes UTF8 characters. I am not sure how I can list all visible UTF8 characters in the filter.

How can I determine if a string is made up of completely invisible characters like above, so I can filter them out? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CharacterSet` for that.

```
let nonWhitespace = CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines.inverted
let containsNonWhitespace = (string.rangeOfCharacter(from: nonWhitespace) != nil)
```

Comment: Thank you, @CharlesSrstka! This is simple and elegant! I added this snippet as a `String` extension in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Trim the string of whitespaces and newlines and see what's left.

```
if someString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty {
    // someString only contains whitespaces and newlines
}
```

Comment: Trimming the whole string is overkill for this use case, since all OP needs to do is find one non-whitespace character. Just searching for it is a lot more efficient.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Yeah but we are talking about strings with just a few characters. The efficiency difference is irrelevant. Your solution has to scan the whole string when it is just whitespaces. There really is very, very little difference.

Comment: I have dozens of such strings in each XML file. Do the execution time or performance impact add up?

Comment: @rmaddy Strings that match the condition—i.e. are all whitespace—will only be a few characters long. Strings that don't match may not be. For all we know, OP could have the full text of Moby Dick stuffed into that XML file (and in case you think that would never happen in real life: [link](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2701.epub.images?session_id=7927d555fd760f5024064d68b19681887df2b936)). At any rate, it is pointless to use an inefficient solution when the efficient solution is just as simple and easy to write.

Comment: @jackxujh No, the difference is so trivial it will never be noticed.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka And strings that have no leading or trailing whitespace won't take any effort to process with this approach. Your concern here falls under "premature optimization". The difference is far too trivial to worry about.